# backup of database using shellscript using crontab fails?

Tags: database, shell, backup, cron, database-backups

My shellscript for taking backup of databse works fine normally.
But when i try to run through crontab there is no backup.

this is mycrontab

```
* * * * * /home/mohan/sohan/backuptest.sh
```

content of backuptest.sh are

```
#!/bin/bash
name=`date +%Y%m%d`.sql
#echo $name
mysqldump -u abc --password=abc my_db > $name
```

backup.sh works fine when normally run .But fails to generate backup when run through crontab

Comment: I think it is because of date command

Comment: Is `mysqldump` in the default path (`/bin` or `/usr/bin` or maybe `/usr/local/bin`) or is it in a different location? Maybe you need to add a `PATH=....` line to your script...

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possibilities... first that your programs/commands cannot be found when run from `cron`, and second that your database cannot be found when run from `cron`.

So, first the programs. You are using `date` and `mysqldump`, so at youir Terminal prompt you need to find where they are located, like this:

```
which date
which mysqldump
```

Then you can either put the full paths that you get as output above into your script, or add a `PATH=` statement at the second line that incorporates both paths.

Secondly, your database. Where is it located? If it is in `/home/mohan/sohan/` for example, you will need to change your script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
name=`/bin/date +%Y%m%d`.sql
cd /home/mohan/sohan
/usr/local/bin/mysqldump -u abc --password=abc my_db > $name
```